# How do i set a time line and it can adjust with my layout

Tags: android

I want to set a time line on my recycler view , but i can't adjust the time line if my content has a lots of words , it means that when height is higher

Here is my layout about time line setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pink_circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line_normal"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"//I set wrap , but if my conten has a lots of word , my layout will be cut , it's not good
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11.5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textType"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textType"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textType"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/textTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textType"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:id="@+id/textDate"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

So i try to change RelativeLayout height 80dp to wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"//change 80dp to wrap_content
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

It becomes to this:
[image]

So how do i set the time line that can be adjusted the height ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a time line? What do you want your UI to look like?

Comment: could you show us what your UI look like ? Maybe attach a picture ?

Comment: I think you haven't tried to use the layout because `android:layout_height="wrap_content"//change 80dp to wrap_content` will do the trick

Comment: ya...sorry my fault , you're correct , it show the right height when i compile .

It's fine now , thanks for responding all of you.